# Proof sets are closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How does one prove that the sets $F_a=\{x\in A:f(x)\geq a\}$ are closed for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and for any real continuous function $f$ defined on $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is immediate from the fact that $f$ is continuous and $\{x\in\Bbb R:x\ge a\}$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$: a function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}[F]$ is closed in $X$ for each closed $F\subseteq Y$.

If you've not seen this characterization, first prove that $f^{-1}[F]$ is closed in $X$ for each closed $F\subseteq Y$ if and only if $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X$ for each open $U\subseteq Y$, and then prove that that characterization is equivalent to whatever definition of continuity you already know.